# testing solidity contracts as a different user

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, solidity

I am inferring that solidity tests will implictly be taking place as a particular user/account.  For example in a test like:

```js
  const instance = await MyCoin.deployed()
  const accountTwo = accounts[1]
  const amount = 100
  await instance.transfer(accountTwo, amount)
```

then the transfer will take place from accounts[0] to accounts[1], with the implication that the user/account doing the transfer is in charge of account[0].

Is there some way to make that explicit and/or change?  So for example that we could write a test that would operate as a user in charge of some other account?

I've been reading https://www.trufflesuite.com/docs/truffle/testing/writing-tests-in-javascript and https://remix-ide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/unittesting_examples.html but I'm not sure I'm seeing anything about how to select a particular user to operate as

https://remix-ide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/unittesting_examples.html#testing-a-method-involving-msg-sender has a special contract with an operation to change an owner variable on a contract, but I don't think that's quite what I want ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define the transaction sender (i.e. the account that executes the function) in the last argument of the function. It's also called the "transaction params". If it's not defined (as in your case), Truffle uses default values.

This snippet executes `transfer(accountTwo, amount)` from `accountThree`. The first two arguments are the arguments of the Solidity function, the third contains the transaction params.

```
await instance.transfer(accountTwo, amount, {from: accountThree})
```

You can find more info in the [docs](https://www.trufflesuite.com/docs/truffle/getting-started/interacting-with-your-contracts#making-a-transaction).